# Dynamic path of image is not working..in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using Image tag in asp.net and I want to pic dynamic path from server,I am using repeater control for this and my code on aspx.cs page is

```
 protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string hotelid = ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblhotelid")).Text.ToString();
        dr = d.FetchDataReader("select hotelname,stateid,cityid from hotelmaster");
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblhotelname")).Text = dr["hotelName"].ToString();
            string stateid, cityid;
            stateid = dr["stateid"].ToString();
            cityid = dr["Cityid"].ToString();

            Image img = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgHotels");
            img.ImageUrl = "~/http://bindassholidays.info/Photos/HotelPhotos" + stateid + cityid + hotelid + "~\"hotelid.jpeg";
        }
    }
```

but image is not found.. please check the
any help should be appriciable...thanks

Comment: You should check the image path.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to debug your code and try to check, which type of image url your code is generating. its generating wrong url, that's the reason your can't see image there.

if you are using **http://** type of url then no need to place **~/** sign. And if you are able to access your file like

```
http://bindassholidays.info/Photos/HotelPhotos/" + stateid + cityid + hotelid + "/hotelid.jpeg"
```

then no need to add **~/**

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work

```
img.ImageUrl = "http://bindassholidays.info/Photos/HotelPhotos/" + stateid + cityid + hotelid + "/hotelid.jpeg";
```

If you know actual path of image load it on any browser and compare its path with your path by breaking on the above line.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the web application root operator (~). However again you are mixing it with absolute path.

I believe it should be something like

```
img.ImageUrl = "~/Photos/HotelPhotos/" + stateid + cityid + hotelid + ".jpeg";
```

Obviously something wrong with the image path. Refer to [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx) for more info on ASP.NET Web Project Paths

Answer (score 0):

First of all i have few questions and answers for this..

1. Why you are using the static paths?

**Answer:**

you can use the below function to get relative URL then combine your iamge folder to that like

```
public string GetWebUrl()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath;
}
```

Now just use the below :

```
GetWebUrl()+Photos/HotelPhotos/" + stateid+"/" + cityid +"/"+hotelid +"/"+"hotelid.jpeg";
```

Hope this works for you